# How to assign a standard email account to contacts in Microsoft Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, vba, microsoft-outlook-2003

I am using Microsoft Outlook 2003 with 6 different POP3 accounts. Now I would like to define a standard account to be used for my contacts or groups of contacts, for example:

```
When sending email to "john.doe@domain.net", email account 1 shall be used.
When sending email to "jane.doe@domain.net", email account 2 shall be used.
```

I think this can't be done using rules so basically I am looking for a VBA solution but I'm not very familiar with Outlook VBA and couldn't find any solution on the web yet.